# react `this.property` is undefined in render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why this.test is undefined? I log `this` it does have the test property and value. I'm confused.

```
class Todo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.test = 123;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this); //is has test as object
    console.log(this.test);
    return <div>{this.test}</div>;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/8k7m05o5pl

Comment: [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)  is invoked _**after**_ a component is mounted, i.e. after first `render` call. That's why `this.test` is undefined (yet).

Answer (score 3):

You should read the React Component Life Cycle [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

`componentDidMount()` is called after the component is rendered, so inside the `render()` function it will be `undefined`. Try to do the assignment in the `constructor()` function or call `this.setState()` inside `componentDidMount()` which will call the `render()` function again.

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` is run after the first render, and `this.test` will not be set until it is run, so it will be `undefined` for the first render.

The reason why `this` has `test` in the console is because you are logging an object which will be updated in the console when it is updated in your code.

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.test = 123;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.test);
    return <div>{this.test}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `this.test` **after** the element is rendered.

Don't store arbitrary values on components for rendering. Use the **state** instead, that is what it is for.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Todo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ test: 123 });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this); //is has test as object
    console.log(this.state && this.state.test);
    return <div>{this.state && this.state.test}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?

```
export default class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       test: ''
    }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({test: 123});
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state); //is has test as object
    console.log(this.state.test);
    return (
       <div>{this.state.test}</div>
    );
  }
}
```